# Quantization of an RGB image

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-image, quantization

I'm doing for a university project a "cartoon-like" filter for an RGB image, so I'm trying to do something to quantize the image.
The only libraries I can use are numpy, matplotlib.pyplot and skimage.

For now I've done this:

```
n = 64

quant[:,:,0] = np.floor_divide(R2, 256//(n//4))*(256//(n//4))
quant[:,:,1] = np.floor_divide(G2, 256//(n//4))*(256//(n//4))
quant[:,:,2] = np.floor_divide(B2, 256//(n//4))*(256//(n//4))

plt.imshow(quant)
```

In this way i achieve my goal, but not totally since I want that n is the exact number of colors that the image can have, nothing more and nothing less.

Any tips?

Comment: Have you tried using Pillow and its [quantize](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/Image.html#PIL.Image.Image.quantize) method?

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something like:

- (1) do [k-means clustering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_clustering) of the color space, k=n.
- (2) replace every pixel with its corresponding cluster color.

For bonus points, you probably want to do this in a perceptual color space, such as [CIELAB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CIELAB_color_space), rather than in RGB directly.

It would be handy to have sklearn to do the k-means clustering, but, failing that, it's not too hard to implement in pure NumPy (and probably a good exercise).

Finally, you can probably replicate this whole thing with [`skimage.segmentation.slic`](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.segmentation.html#skimage.segmentation.slic). SLIC does fancier things, clustering in both spatial and color space, but you can play around with the `compactness`, `convert2lab`, and `enforce_connectivity` parameters to force it to cluster only in color space.